# Ошибка в Eclipse Window Builder: This is not a GUI class and can't be edited graphically?

Tags: java, eclipse

Появилась ошибка в Eclipse Window Builder [image: Окно с ошибкой]
Я в eclipse новичок, не знаю как исправить!

Comment: [Это](http://naazvilantakath.blogspot.com/2013/06/eclipse-window-buider-error-this-is-not.html?m=1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы указали под класс? Должно работать. Так как это распространенная ошибка (Как было у меня)